# I need some help migrating from react-router-redux to connected-react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, connected-react-router

I am trying to upgrade my existing codebase and moving from react-router-redux to connected react-router.
Couldn't find much resources on migration, however [this](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/issues/74#issuecomment-443785454) has helped me significantly.

I am unable to find any resource on how to get access to the router object with connected-react-router insided a react component. With react-router-redux i was getting it in the context.

Comment: You could access like any other reducer.

Comment: Have you defined the `router: connectRouter(history),` in your root reducer?

Comment: @Christiaan yes i have

Comment: @10101010 could you elaborate, i can get the router object from the state but thats not what i am looking for

Comment: Then I didn't understand your question.

Comment: do you want to use a HOC like `withRouter` in react-router-redux?

Comment: in react-router-redux you can access the router object in the context which has access to all the router functions, params, push etc. I want to get access to the same router object or need to figure out the migration procedure to get the same functionality with connected-react-router.

Comment: Could you add some code which shows accessing the router object from the context?